# How to type a type paramater in react Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a generic hook that returns a function that clears the filter values.

I'm not passing any parameters, just a type parameter. `FilterParams` will be in the shape of example `SomeFilterParams`.

```
//... 

export const useBuildClearValue = <FilterParams>() => {
  const {
    setFieldValue,
  } = useFormikContext();

  const buildClearValue = useCallback((inputName: keyof FilterParams) => {
    return () => {
      setFieldValue(inputName, null); //error is here
    };
  }, [
    setFieldValue,
  ]);

  return buildClearValue;

};

//... USAGE

type SomeFilterParams = {
  name?: string;
  status?: string;
}

const buildClearValue = useBuildClearValue<SomeFilterParams>();
```

TS is not happy with `inputName` in the `setFieldValue`.

Error:  `Argument of type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`

I guess that I need to type the passed type itself and enforce the key as a string and value as a string as well.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show what the signature of `setFieldValue` is, but based on the error and your example usage, it looks like it takes a property name as a string and a value to set for that property. However, `keyof T` without any constraints on `T` is defined as any of the types that are valid for keys in JavaScript, which is strings, numbers, and symbols. Because you can't pass a number or symbol to `setFieldValue`, you get this error.

What you want is to restrict the `input` to only the string property names of your generic type. You can do that by filtering all number and symbol keys out using a conditional mapped type.

Here's a simplified example, removing the React and Formik-specific parts.

```js
declare const setFieldValue: (property: string, value: unknown) => void;

export const useBuildClearValue = <T,>() => {
  return (inputName: Exclude<keyof T, number | symbol>) => {
    return () => {
      setFieldValue(inputName, null);
    };
  };
};

type SomeFilterParams = {
  name?: string;
  status?: string;
}

const buildClearValue = useBuildClearValue<SomeFilterParams>();
buildClearValue("name");
buildClearValue("status");
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3mkGBiAliBMAGpQQCuIAXPABQAOMSjIMGAnnZjASgHMANPABuFanUooA1iiQB3FAEp4AXgB8YpAWABuAFAGQAD0ZIOiVJniUcAIUoESAYQghY5KgjXwAPAAqQhr0qprwAN4G8PBwGJQwKAz8jJQYAHJQALa08ACiJpCUoH4yIJxIAGbwQfAolFkARuzwAD7YnE1IEBphWlExMXEJSaHq-dGDMTj4RCRe1PQpaZk5IvUQEMqGUwC+O-D7BkcGXGzwAMpIOYQQGOwACrDZaOqRkyjZIAD8PBh8ggOmCg8TQv2w-34AkMuyMyHQWEaTlc7k8Eh8tgcyOAbg8MAWID8VxuznuMCeMBeIW2BiRzhxqPx6PoACJPjkWTS6Si8QTWcDQZy9EA)